# Having trouble converting df index to datetime object

Tags: datetime, pandas

So this is my dataframe

```
                Ticker                           Owner  \
SEC Form 4                                               
Nov 09 02:19 PM    HSY                   HERSHEY TRUST  
Nov 09 02:05 PM    HSY                HERSHEY TRUST CO   
Nov 09 02:03 PM   WDFC                PITTARD DANIEL E   
Nov 09 01:34 PM   IMGN                   Enyedy Mark J   
Nov 09 01:25 PM    ORI                   ZUCARO ALDO C
```

I'm trying to convert the index(SEC Form 4) into a datetime object, so I can use that object's methods. However, I like the current format style of the date (Nov 09 02:19 PM) and *don't* want to replace it with something like (2016-11-09 14:19).

```
pd.to_datetime(df.index, format = '%b %d')
pd.to_datetime(df.index, format = '%b %d %I:%M %p' )
```

I played around with some of these format parameters but it seems these change  the look display style of the date into something like (2016-11-09 14:19:00) format, which is not the format that I want.

I even tried to see if there was a dtype datetime that I can just convert to (so I won't have to change the display look)  but I had no luck finding such a dtype.

http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.dtypes.html

Thank you.

Comment: the format param specifies the format fields for conversion it doesn't affect the display, you can use `dt.strftime` after conversion but that yields a string which is not that useful, you'd be better to convert it to a datetime and just live with the display format if you want to make filtering easier

Comment: Ah, I see. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you missed to append the year since it is not specified in the data. Here is a possible solution.

```
zz = """"SEC Form 4"  Ticker  Owner                                               
"Nov 09 02:19 PM"    "HSY"                   "HERSHEY TRUST"
"Nov 09 02:05 PM"    HSY                "HERSHEY TRUST CO"   
"Nov 09 02:03 PM"   WDFC                "PITTARD DANIEL E"   
"Nov 09 01:34 PM"   IMGN                   "Enyedy Mark J"   
"Nov 09 01:25 PM"    ORI                   "ZUCARO ALDO C"   
"""

df = pd.read_table(io.StringIO(zz), delim_whitespace=True)
df.set_index('SEC Form 4', inplace=True)
# Adding the missing year
df.index = '2016 ' + df.index
# There is no need to detail the expected format
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)

print(df.index.dtype)
print(df)
# datetime64[ns]
#                     Ticker             Owner
# 2016-11-09 14:19:00    HSY     HERSHEY TRUST
# 2016-11-09 14:05:00    HSY  HERSHEY TRUST CO
# 2016-11-09 14:03:00   WDFC  PITTARD DANIEL E
# 2016-11-09 13:34:00   IMGN     Enyedy Mark J
# 2016-11-09 13:25:00    ORI     ZUCARO ALDO C
```

Comment: Hi Romain. Actually, the date was missing for the data, but I will try to include it via the code you showed me.  My original question actually was if there as way to retain ""Nov 09 01:25 PM"" display format while  converting it into datetime object. I think I worded my question vaguely so I will edit it. Thank you so much.